# During relabance what is the state of StreamThreads?

Tags: apache-kafka, apache-kafka-streams

I am learning `Kafka Stream processors` and referring to various online materials. During rebalance what would be state of `StreamThreads` and so `StreamTasks`. Are `StreamThreads` in "sleeping" stage or gets destroyed and created afresh after rebalance?

I am still learning the concepts,so please pardon if this is a basic concept.

Comment: Kafka Streams is not explicit to Confluent. Confluent-kafka tag is for librdkafka based libraries

Comment: Thanks for correcting, will keep this in mind.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`REBALANCING` is an explicit state

> REBALANCING if any of its threads is in PARTITION_REVOKED or PARTITIONS_ASSIGNED state - REBALANCING state will transit to RUNNING if all of its threads are in RUNNING state

https://kafka.apache.org/24/javadoc/org/apache/kafka/streams/KafkaStreams.State.html

Comment: Does "explicit" state mean "framework" specific state? If I understood correctly, can "real threads" be in "RUNNING" state (the Thread States in this context of Threads); even though stream in "REBALANCING" state?

Comment: Yes, framework state. Java threads are always running, if that's what you mean. Otherwise, as it says "if **any of its threads** is in PARTITION_REVOKED or PARTITIONS_ASSIGNED state". If all are running, then the stream is healthy and running as well